# Does agnosticism require absolution?

Tags: existentialism, agnosticism

Can agnosticism be interpreted as requiring an absolute or ubiquitous force in living?

By absolute I generalize a concept "as is": the same idea as irrefutable, or governing without using what I feel are partial ideas such as omnipotence, something irrefutable, and ultimate.

Agnosticism believes in a greater force or power of which it's nature is inconceivable to an absolute being (or, at least, this is the idea I have derived.) If so why is it we require an absolute force in our being?

•Is it an aspect of our perception, of how we view multidimensional or even ubiquitous ideas linearly?

•Or an answer for the lack of knowledge we posses?

•Or even our rationality theorizing that life must posses a full or infallible entity that governs with multi-dimensional perspective and/or a being of non-conformity?

•Even a sense of ubiquitous presence that we derive all knowledge and existence from?

Comment: [absolution](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absolution) ???

Comment: Trying to get the same idea as irrefutable, or governing without using what I feel are partial ideas such as omnipotence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, agnosticism does not require absolution.

Agnosticism is merely ignorance of deity, specifically agnosticism is lack of knowledge regarding deity, and has nothing to do with belief. From the Greek, the "[a](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=a-)" in [agnostic](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=agnostic) means "not" or "lack of" and "[gnostic](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gnostic)" means "known". Not to confuse the person with the position, but as an example of the terms use, an atheist gnostic lacks belief in deity and claims knowledge that deity does not exist. An agnostic theist believes in deity but claims to lack knowledge regarding deity.

Yes, anything can be interpreted any way you please - such is [hermeneutics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hermeneutics/#HermCirc).

When you say "absolution" do you mean it in the sense of "absolving sin" or in the sense of something "absolute" (i.e. "does agnosticism require absolutes, absoluteness, an absolute, absolutism, et cetera)? In either sense and with the clarification from your comment, agnosticism does not require it. The agnostic position merely lacks knowledge; it is ignorance of deity.

In short, agnosticism is a position regarding knowledge, not belief.